# How do I put a function into a Powershell script file that I want to be able to call directly?

Tags: powershell

If I have a powershell script file that I want to be able to call directly, called Find-MyThing how do I add a function into it for it to use?

Basically, I want to write a file like this:

```
Param(
[Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
  $ThingReference)

process{
     $intermediateValue =  DoSomeProcessing($ThingReference)
     $finalValue = DoSomeMoreProcessing($intermediateValue)
     return $finalValue
}

Function DoSomeProcessing($thing){...}

Function DoSomeMoreProcessing($thing){...}
```

But Powershell doesn't like me having a separate functions in the file.  I can wrap up the main processing in a function, but then there's no way to actually call it from outside the file.

Is this possible?  Or should I be approaching things entirely differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it!

I can put the functions in the begin block, and that defines them for use later!

```
Param(
  [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
  $ThingReference)

begin{
Function DoSomeProcessing($thing){...}

Function DoSomeMoreProcessing($thing){...}
}


process{
     $intermediateValue =  DoSomeProcessing($ThingReference)
     $finalValue = DoSomeMoreProcessing($intermediateValue)
     return $finalValue
}
```

Comment: They don't have to be in the begin block. They just have to be anywhere in the file before you actually try to call them.

Comment: If I put the functions in outside the begin block then it won't run - It gives me an error:
Get-Process : Cannot evaluate parameter 'Name' because its argument is specified as a script block and there is no input. A script block
cannot be evaluated without input.

Comment: @EBGreen is wrong: if you want to use process block (and with variable declared as binding `ValueFromPipeline` you have to) than definition have to be in the `begin` block. BTW: it's answer to your question, so you should mark it as one. I wrote a blog post about the error you got a while ago (http://becomelotr.wordpress.com/2011/10/25/begin-process-end/)

Comment: Thanks Bartek - and that's a good post.  I'll accept my answer as soon as I can (it has to be two days, apparently.)